# Setting permissions on branch folders rather than specific branches

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I am currently using Azure DevOps and we have a branching strategy that lets developers share work on any branch in `collab/app/*`. I would like to add enhanced permissions to any branch that is created under the `collab` folder (force push for example).

All I have been able to see is how to add security to a single branch, however our branches are so short lived we would spend too much time forever updating the security on every branch we create.

Any resources or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Git itself has no concept of security (at all, much less via branch names). Obviously value-added sites like Azure *do*, but the details are up to each site, so I've snipped the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have branch with folders (`folderName\branchName`) you can give permissions to the folders:

[image]

Just go to the project settings -> Repositories -> Select the repo -> Click on "Security" tab in the right -> scroll down and select a folder (then you see the view in the above screenshot).